# How to capture Hebrew with regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, hebrew

I'm trying to catch a section of Hebrew text (the origin is comments on a news site) using the following regex:

```
[\u0590-\u05FF \\p{Graph} \\s]+
```

It works for most comments but some comments are missed.

I've tried to debug this and it seems there's a Hebrew letter that doesn't match the pattern.

When I extract this letter and print it's integer value it seems to be correct but still the regex doesn't catch it...

Ideas?

Comment: Do you use `Pattern.UNICODE_CASE` inside your `Pattern.compile` method?

Comment: Try it: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("YOUR_REGEX", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);`

Comment: *Which* Hebrew letter doesn't match the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more sematically correct to use `\p{InHebrew}` instead of `\u0590-\u05FF`

Also you need to match punctuation, digits (at least, world-common ones) and different kind of spaces.
I don't know what is `\p{Graph}` and are there any Hebrew-specific punctuation symbols, but it seemed, you missed some parts.