# detect Hebrew letters in strings

Tags: java, string

I am trying to write some code that changes files with hebrew letters in them to valid english names insted, but i am having problems understading how to detect those files, i built a filter for listfiles function.

Also i have searched online and i couldn't find an answer but this one:

[How to tell if a string contains characters in Hebrew using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549012/how-to-tell-if-a-string-contains-characters-in-hebrew-using-php)

but its not java, its php.
any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987119/how-to-capture-hebrew-with-regex-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{InHebrew}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987119/how-to-capture-hebrew-with-regex-in-java

Answer (score 7):

To test that the String str contains Hebrew letters use:

str.matches (".*[א-ת]+.*")

returns true if str contains Hebrew letters.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) page, there is a regex category for unicode Hebrew literals. This regex: `\\p{Hebrew}` should yield true should a string contain a Hebrew literal.

Answer (score 2):

Chosen answer is not working in my case with mixed English and Hebrew string.

```
    String fileName = "ףךלחףךלחץ.msg";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{InHebrew}", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);

    System.out.println(p.matcher(fileName).matches());  //false
```

Output: false.

To check if string **contains** some Hebrew letters next code used:

```
    String fileName = "ףךלחףךלחץ.msg";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{InHebrew}", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher m = null;

    boolean hebrewDetected = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < fileName.length() && !hebrewDetected; i++){
        String letter = fileName.charAt(i) + "";
        m = p.matcher(letter);
        hebrewDetected = m.matches();
        if (hebrewDetected){
             break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("hebrewDetected=" + hebrewDetected ); //true
```

Output : true.